# Why sometimes the call stack in a dump file does not looks correct?

Tags: visual-c++

Recently We have a production issue with application freezed, we tried to break in and analyse the dump file, unfortunately the call stack for the dump file does not looks good and hard to track down the cause of the freeze.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application hung rather than crashed, try loading into windbg and run `!analyze -v -hang` or try using [adplus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350) in hang mode.  This tries to determine the cause of the hang which should give you a more meaningful call stack.  The `!locks` command can be useful too if you have deadlock by showing you what is blocking on a resource.

Comment: Thanks, I may try these commands in semi-production enviroment if I can reproduce it. For production, the techs don't have time wait for us to debug into it.

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons why a call stack might look incorrect:

1. The stack might be corrupted. If the stack was corrupted for some reason (for instance, due to an overflow of a buffer which was allocated on the stack), all the stack frames are destroyed. This makes it impossible to compute the list of callers.
2. The symbols you use (if any) might not be appropriate for the binary which crashed. You need to use the exact same symbols which were used when compiling the binary. A slight change to the source code can render all the symbols invalid.

Comment: The symbols should be match the binary. probably the stack was corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

If you call into the Windows API's, which then call back into you on the same thread (via Windows message handlers, for instance), it is not uncommon for the operations in the Windows DLL's to use stack conventions that the debugger cannot interpret.  There's no requirement that the stack be traceable all the time during the execution of a c/c++ function/method, the stack-related registers can be re-used for other purposes and the standard places of stashing stack information can be ignored.  I see this a lot in Windows.